# printing stl containers with gdb 7.0

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I have installed GDB 7.0 and python per the following [instructions](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).  In the same manual, there is a mention of this file [stl-views-1.0.3.gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=stl-views-1.0.3.gdb). What confuses me is where it should be placed in order to enable pretty printing of stl containers. Would someone also explain to me all of this work?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the gdb:

```
source {full_path}stl-views-1.0.3.gdb
```

now you'll have new commands, such as `pvector, plist, pmap` and more (replace **{full_path}** with the full path to the file.

You can also put the command `source stl-views-1.0.3.gdb` in `~/.gdbinit` - and then you'll have it automatically every time you launch gdb.

Comment: Do I have to do it every time I load gdb? Can it be done by default?  Shuold stl-views-1.0.3.gdb be located in the current working directory?

Comment: Can't you just put it in your `~/.gdbinit`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? So I start gdb and I type that? I just get `No such file or directory.`

Comment: @Kache4 do you actually have the file?  source stl-views-1.0.3.gdb
 is NOT a command, but rather a command followed by the file name, although you've probably figured this out by now.

Comment: @Andrei: I guess not. `locate` doesn't find anything. Where can I get it? Quick Google search and search using Ubuntu synaptic didn't get me anything.

Comment: @Kache4: there's a link in the question itself

Comment: I agree with "Employed Russian". This is the old - pre gdb7 - way of doing things. See the related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492020/how-to-view-contents-of-stl-containers-using-gdb-7-x

Comment: @Drakosha   Hi, assume `pvector` works, what if I have a data structure which has vectors inside a vector (vector<vector<int> >)?  How can I print elements of the inner vectors?

Comment: ah  i see. for the situation I described above,  the `pvector` command automatically prints the elements of the inner vectors.   https://blog.csdn.net/cws1214/article/details/8500730     http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt

Answer (score 14):

As far as I can tell, stl-views are the *old* way to examine STL containers, and are *inferior* to the new python support in almost every way.

You should use `libstdcxx_printers` python pretty-printers instead.

Comment: What is the difference between libstdcxx_printers and stl-views then?

Comment: The libstdcxx_printers are shipped and maintained as part of GCC, so they always match the version of the compiler you're using and know about changes to the container internals. The python  printing is enabled automatically, is far more powerful and is more easily extended to your own types.

Comment: The instructions for getting libstdcxx pretty printers are at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.gdb .

Answer (score 0):

FYI, these instructions dont work on Ubuntu lucid at least.
See [this bug i just filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/599895)