# how to view contents of STL containers using GDB 7.x

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I have been using the macro solution, as it is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463198/printing-stl-containers-with-gdb-7-0). However, there is a mention on how to view them without macros. I am referring to GDB version 7 and above.

Would someone illustrate how?

Thanks

Comment: which numeric version of gdb are you talking about

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Get the python viewers from SVN

```
svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
```

Add the following to your `~/.gdbinit`

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/pretty-printers/dir')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Then print should just work:

```
std::map<int, std::string> the_map;
the_map[23] = "hello";
the_map[1024] = "world";
```

In gdb:

```
(gdb) print the_map 
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = { [23] = "hello", [1024] = "world" }
```

To get back to the old view use `print /r` (`/r` is for raw).

See also: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: And how to actually use it in GDB to print the contents?  Is anything  need to be set. thx

Comment: Once that load code is in .gdbinit, then print should just work, to get back to the old view, you do a print /r (/r is for raw)
(formatting apparently sucks in comments, my apologies)

        std::map<int, std::string> the_map;
        the_map[23] = "hello";
        the_map[1024] = "world";

(gdb) print the_map
$1 = std::map with 2 elements = {
  [23] = "hello",
  [1024] = "world"
}

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include this information in your comment. That way the formatting wont suck.

Comment: please put this code sample in the answer. I can't read it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The libstdcxx_printers are included with recent versions of GCC, so if you're using GCC 4.5 or later then you don't need to do anything, pretty printing Just Works.

```
(gdb) p v
$1 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 3 = {std::set with 3 elements = {
    [0] = 1, [1] = 2, [2] = 3}, std::set with 2 elements = {[0] = 12, 
    [1] = 13}, std::set with 1 elements = {[0] = 23}}
(gdb) p v[1]
$2 = std::set with 2 elements = {[0] = 12, [1] = 13}
```

To disable the pretty printing use `p/r` or `print/r` to get "raw" output.