# eclipse CDT pretty-printing not working for strings

Tags: c++, string, eclipse, gdb, pretty-print

I am trying to Get gdb pretty-print working in eclipse, it seems to be working for all stl elements and containers baring `std::string`

basically if i have a vector like:

```
std::vector<std::string> m_vec = {"hello" , "world"};
```

each element of the vector shows a string and it shows the contents like "hello" and "world".

but if i have a code like

```
std::string m_string = "hello world";
```

`m_string` shows up empty, even though i can do string operations on the contents. Not sure why only strings alone is causing as issue with pretty print.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

**Edited**:

```
Few more details regarding the setup:
    IDE: Eclipse Luna 4.4.2
    Compiler: Cygwin g++ 5.4.0
    Debugger: Cygwin gdb 7.10.1
    phython : Cygwin phython 3.6
```

**Update**: Don't know how exactly, but windows restart solved it, can see string now in preety-print.

Comment: gdb **pretty-print** was deprecated in later versions of gdb. Please check the support

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Where do you get the info that the gdb pretty print support is deprecated?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937052/4690576). See if this helps.

Comment: @AmeyaVS In CDT source code. I use Ubuntu, am not aware of the package to be installed. I encountered a similar problem when I tried to do remote debugging an c application I am not getting the control back(Similar to going to infinite loop) when investigated I am using older gdb configuration for newer version of gdb. Sorry not getting exact link for the information source, once I have will update. Thanks

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Please have a look [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html#Pretty-Printing) GDB Pretty printing is quite available in GDB 8.x version releases.

Comment: Can you update the question about the environment you are using e.g.: compiler version and the system (Windows: MinGW/Cygwin or Linux or macOS) you are using?

Answer (score 1):

For adding support for gdb pretty-printing in cygwin you need the following file available:
`/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll-gdb.py`

It is available in `gcc-debuginfo-5.4.0-1` package in cygwin package installer.

**Note:** This might break once packages get updated in Cygwin repository. So you will need to again locate this file in the [Cygwin package search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi).

**Update:** Check the version of python interpreter supported by gdb by running the following commands in the gdb console:

```
(cygwin console) $ gdb
(gdb) python
>import sys
>print(sys.version)
>end
```

You should see output something like this(in my case it defaults to `python2.7` interpreter):

```
2.7.13 (default, Mar 13 2017, 20:56:15)
[GCC 5.4.0]
```

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me, pretty print not working for STL containers when debugging with Visual Studio Code and Cygwin. Python 3.8 works fine for me, though.